# Cannot connect CSS to my HTML

Tags: css, html

I keep trying and trying but I have no idea what the issue is.

Linked is a [picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO5e6.png) showing the source code and directory structure of my site.

Got answer thanks

Comment: Please be more specific on your question and post some code you have tried.

Comment: it seems that your index.html is within the img folder.

Comment: I'm sorry I've never used website I tried to add image but it didn't work at first, image it up now. Thanks for the feedback and letting me know there was zero context.

Comment: Thank you, where does my index.html file need to be?

Comment: Please provide code or link to code to avoid excessive typing problems that others who try to help you face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `index.html` page to your `Websitename` directory. Currently your page is trying to find the `css` directory inside of the `img` directory and of course it doesn't exist there.

Comment: OHHHH BRILLIANT thank you so much, so very sorry for the dumb question. I am a student who is taking this class that is ONLY offered online at my campus. I was very much going crazy. Thank you thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO Akuden. Please accept the answer if this resolved your issue.